# Post image with restsharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm trying to post image to Instagram using my private API. I can do it successfully using the graph API but I'm trying to do it with my private API as a sort of challenge but there's a week I'm stuck.

```
var tstamp = Bridge.UnixMs;
        var request = new RestRequest($"/rupload_igvideo/fb_uploader_{tstamp}", Method.Options);
        request.AddHeader("Host", "i.instagram.com");
        request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
        request.AddHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method", "GET");
        request.AddHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "x-asbd-id,x-ig-app-id");
        request.AddHeader("Origin", "https://www.instagram.com");
        request.AddHeader("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors");
        request.AddHeader("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-site");
        request.AddHeader("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty");
        request.AddHeader("Referer", "https://www.instagram.com/");
        request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        request.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8");
        request.AddHeader("X-CSRFToken", Data.jar!["csrftoken"]);
        request.AddHeader("X-IG-App-ID", Data.appId!);
        request.AddHeader("X-IG-WWW-Claim", Data.hmac!);
        request.AddHeader("X-Instagram-AJAX", Data.ajax!);
        request.AddHeader("Cookie", $"{Data.csrf} {Data.datr} {Data.ds} {Data.did}" +
            $"{Data.nrcb} {Data.ses} {Data.bid} {Data.bts} {Data.mid!.Replace(";", "")}");
        var body = @"";
        request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        var response = await req.Client().ExecuteAsync(request);
```

this request above is successful.

```
request = new RestRequest($"/rupload_igvideo/fb_uploader_{tstamp}", Method.Get);
        request.AddHeader("Host", "i.instagram.com");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
        request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
        request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-platform", "\"Windows\"");
        request.AddHeader("Origin", "https://www.instagram.com");
        request.AddHeader("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-site");
        request.AddHeader("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors");
        request.AddHeader("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty");
        request.AddHeader("Referer", "https://www.instagram.com/");
        request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        request.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8");
        request.AddHeader("Cookie", $"{Data.csrf} {Data.datr} {Data.ds} {Data.did}" +
                        $"{Data.nrcb} {Data.ses} {Data.bid} {Data.bts} {Data.mid!.Replace(";", "")}"); 
        response = await req.Client().ExecuteAsync(request);
```

this code above succesful too.

```
byte[] vBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Bureau\nurf.mp4");
        
        body = $@"{vBytes}";
        string size = body.Length.ToString();
        request = new RestRequest($"/rupload_igvideo/fb_uploader_{tstamp}", Method.Post);
        request.AddHeader("Host", "i.instagram.com");
        request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Length", $"{size}");
        request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua", "\"Not.A/Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"114\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"114\"");
        request.AddHeader("X-Entity-Name", $"fb_uploader_{tstamp}");
        request.AddHeader("Offset", "0");
        request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
        request.AddHeader("X-Instagram-AJAX", Data.ajax!);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
        request.AddHeader("X-Instagram-Rupload-Params", @$"{{""client-passthrough"":""1"",
                                                            ""is_clips_video"":""1"",
                                                            ""is_sidecar"":""0"",
                                                            ""media_type"":2,
                                                            ""for_album"":false,
                                                            ""video_format"":"""",
                                                            ""upload_id"":""{tstamp}"",
                                                            ""upload_media_duration_ms"":30700,
                                                            ""upload_media_height"":427,
                                                            ""upload_media_width"":240,
                                                            ""video_transform"":null,
                                                            ""video_edit_params"":{{""crop_height"":240,
                                                            ""crop_width"":240,""crop_x1"":0,
                                                            ""crop_y1"":93,
                                                            ""mute"":false,
                                                            ""trim_end"":30.7,
                                                            ""trim_start"":0}}}}"); ;
        request.AddHeader("X-Entity-Length", $"{size}");
        request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-platform", "\"Windows\"");
        request.AddHeader("Origin", "https://www.instagram.com");
        request.AddHeader("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-site");
        request.AddHeader("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors");
        request.AddHeader("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty");
        request.AddHeader("Referer", "https://www.instagram.com/");
        request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        request.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8");
        request.AddHeader("Cookie", $"{Data.csrf} {Data.datr} {Data.ds} {Data.did}" +
                                    $"{Data.nrcb} {Data.ses} {Data.bid} {Data.bts} {Data.mid!.Replace(";", "")}"); 
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");            
        request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        response = await req.Client().ExecuteAsync(request);
```

but this one give internal server error. I know it may not be good anyway. When catching request in fiddler, the "body" part is a bunch of gibberish, probably "binary data" so I have no clue how to create the request.

Comment: The body is GZIP which is compressed and must be decompressed.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=net-7.0  Yu have in your code : request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");

Answer (score 1):

and thank you all for replies.

@Danial Sa'adati

I've studied your code but post request with all theses bytes/deserializations and unknown terms...

```
restClient.AddHandler("application/octet-stream", new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer());  
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
```

Why there is a "restClient.AddHandler" and a "request.AddHeader" what is their differents functions?

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();  
dict.Add("FILE_EXT", ext);  
dict.Add("FILE_MIME_TYPE", mime);
```

So if i understand correctly, you're adding headers to a dictionary but one thing i dont get. What the objects should be?

```
byte[] imageBytes;  
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Users\anand.thakur\Desktop\1.wmv", FileMode.Open))  

{  
    imageBytes = new BinaryReader(fs).ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);  
}  
string image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```

You lost me on this part, i dont understand the mix between videos and images.

```
dict.Add("IMAGE_DATA", image);  
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict));  
request.AddParameter("application/octet-stream", data, ParameterType.RequestBody);  
var response = restClient.Execute(request);  
JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
Dictionary<string, object> dict1 = json.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(response.Content);
```

Well im pretty lost. Would you explain me if you dont mind.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this problem using instruction from the link below:

[Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/uploading-streamimages-to-rest-api-using-restsharp/)